Examples of complex structures that result in non-biholomorphic spaces
I'm going over some basics related to complex structures on complex manifolds. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Are there some elementary examples on where we can equip $M$ with two complex structures which result in non-biholomorphic complex manifolds?
Also, is there any way to understand under which kinds of circumstances two such complex structures will result in biholomorphic complex manifolds?

$\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb D$ are diffeomorphic but not biholomorphic, by Liouville's theorem. It can be shown (uniformization theorem) that there is only one complex structure on the (real) 2-sphere $S^2$. More generally, you may want to look up Teichmüller spaces

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is the universal covering space of $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, any holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1\to\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$ between two complex tori lifts to a holomorphic map $F:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $F_1,F_2$ are both lifts of $f$. Define $G=F_1-F_2$ and let $\pi_i:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_i$ be the projection maps. Then for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ we get
\begin{align*}
    f\circ\pi_1(z)=\pi_2\circ F_1(z)=\pi_2\circ F_2(z)\implies \pi_2\circ F_1(z)-\pi_2\circ F_2(0)=0\implies G(z)\in \Lambda_2
\end{align*}
By continuity of $G$ and the fact that a lattice is discrete, we must have $G=\text{const.}\in\Lambda_2$. Now, we claim that $F(z)=\alpha z+\beta$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha \Lambda_1\subseteq\Lambda_2$. For $\lambda\in\Lambda_1$, define $G_\lambda(z)=F(z+\lambda)-F(z)$. Since $F(z)$ and $F(z+\lambda)$ are both lifts of $f$, we must have $G_\lambda(z)\in\Lambda_2$ constant. Furthermore, $\frac{d}{dz}F(z+\lambda)=\frac{d}{dz}F(z)$ so that $\frac{d}{dz}F$ is $\Lambda_1$-periodic. Thus, it is a bounded, holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, which must be constant. It follows that $F(z)=\alpha z+\beta$ for some complex numbers $\alpha,\beta$. Finally, if $\lambda\in \Lambda_1$, then $G_\lambda(0)=\alpha \lambda+\beta-\beta=\alpha \lambda\in\Lambda_2$, so indeed $\alpha\Lambda_1\subseteq\Lambda_2$.
With that background, let's prove:
Theorem. Two complex tori $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1$ and $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists an $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^\times$ such that $\alpha\Lambda_1=\Lambda_2$.
Suppose $\alpha\Lambda_1=\Lambda_2$. Let $m_\alpha(z)=\alpha z$. Since $m_\alpha(\Lambda_1)=\Lambda_2$, this descends to a holomorphic map $\widetilde{m}_\alpha:\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1\to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$, which has a holomorphic inverse given by $\widetilde{m}_{\alpha^{-1}}:\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2\to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1$ so that $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1\cong \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$.
Conversely, suppose $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1\cong \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$. Let $f:\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1\to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$ be a biholomorphism, with lift $F:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, and inverse lift $G:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. Then $F(z)=\alpha z+\beta$ and $G(z)=\gamma z+\delta$. Looking at $F\circ G(z)=\alpha\gamma z+\alpha\delta+\beta$, we see that $\alpha\gamma=1$. Since $\alpha\neq 0\neq\gamma$,
\begin{align*}
    \alpha\Lambda_1\subseteq\Lambda_2\quad\quad \gamma\Lambda_2\subseteq\Lambda_1\implies\\
    \alpha\gamma\Lambda_1=\Lambda_1\subseteq\gamma\Lambda_2\subseteq\Lambda_1\quad\quad \alpha\gamma\Lambda_2=\Lambda_2\subseteq\alpha\Lambda_1\subseteq\Lambda_2
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\alpha\Lambda_1=\Lambda_2$.
This was example 10 taken verbatim from my master's thesis.
